# Problem in adding more than 5 button in tab bar controller in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hello everybody i need your help.

I am making a tab bar based application in iphone. i have more than 5 button to show in tab bar. when i did it, five button displayed fifth button is more..... but when i clicked on more then more button came in a table view not in tab bar.

Comment: That is how tabs are supposed to work on iOS

Comment: But i want to show the more item in tab bar not in table view .Is there any idea for doing this

Answer (score 2):

That's how it works. From the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW2):

> If you add more than five items to the
>   viewControllers property, the tab bar
>   controller automatically inserts a
>   special view controller (called the
>   More view controller) to handle the
>   display of the additional items. The
>   More view controller provides a custom
>   interface that lists the additional
>   view controllers in a table, which can
>   expand to accommodate any number of
>   view controllers. The More view
>   controller cannot be customized or
>   selected and does not appear in any of
>   the view controller lists managed by
>   the tab bar controller. For the most
>   part, it appears automatically when it
>   is needed and is separate from your
>   custom content. You can get a
>   reference to it though by accessing
>   the moreNavigationController property
>   of UITabBarController.

Answer (score 1):

That is intended behavior and not an issue, if you read the viewController Programming guide you could have seen that right away: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457